# How can I fetch data to graphql server when I want

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm Trying to use graphql and apollo to handle data.

I created API server with graphql and created web server with React
In the official [document](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/)

It says I can fetch data like this

```js
function Dogs({ onDogSelected }) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);

  if (loading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return (
    <select name="dog" onChange={onDogSelected}>
      {data.dogs.map(dog => (
        <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
          {dog.breed}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

There's no problem yet. However, if I add some state in this `Dogs` component  like

```js
const [someList, setSomeList] = useState([]);
```

Whenever someList is changed so that Dogs component re-rendered, useQuery also run again. It is definitely not what I want. I want to control the timing when to fetch data. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the query outside of the `Dogs` rendering component:

```
function Dogs({ onDogSelected, data }) {

  return (
    <select name="dog" onChange={onDogSelected}>
      {data.dogs.map(dog => (
        <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
          {dog.breed}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}

function DoStuffHere() {
  const [someList, setSomeList] = useState([]);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);
  if (loading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
  if (someList.length){
    console.log("do someList stuff");
  }
  return (<Dogs data={data} onDogSelected={(x) => {
    // setSomeList? here?
  }} />)
}
```

Moving the query outside the `Dogs`, component will ensure that the `Dogs` component does not refetch when it rerenders.